# What is the derivative of $x^{x^{x^{x^{.^{.^{.}}}}}}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, infinity, implicit-differentiation

Here is my attempt:

Substituting y for infinite x powers:

$$x^{x^{x^{x^{.^{.^{.}}}}}}=y → x^y=y $$

Giving:
$$x=y^{\frac{1}{y}}$$

Take natural logs & differentiate with respect to $y$:
$$ln(x)=ln(y^\frac{1}{y}) → ln(x)=\frac{1}{y}ln(y^\frac{1}{y})$$
$$\frac{1}{x}\frac{dx}{dy}=-\frac{1}{y^2}ln(y)+\frac{1}{y^2}$$
$$\frac{dx}{dy}=x\left(\frac{1-ln(y)}{y^2}\right)$$

Sub. in $y^{\frac{1}{y}}$ for $x$:
$$\frac{dx}{dy}=y^{\frac{1}{y}}\left(\frac{1-ln(y)}{y^2}\right)$$
$$\frac{dx}{dy}=y^{\frac{1}{y}-2}\left(1-ln(y)\right)$$

Inverse $\frac{dx}{dy}$ to get $\frac{dy}{dx}$:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\left[y^{\frac{1}{y}-2}\left(1-ln(y)\right)\right]^{-1}$$
Therefore: 
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y^{2-\frac{1}{y}}}{1-ln(y)}$$

Have I made a mistake anywhere?
Have I made a false assumption? Please kindly provide some guidance, thanks.

Comment: I don't see a problem with this per se, but this derivative only exists where the function itself converges, which seems like a non-trivial problem in its own right.

Comment: @AlfredYerger convergence is $e^{-e}\leq x\leq e^{1/e}$

Comment: Thanks, wasn't able to find the same question initially.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that you could do it faster considering the implicit function $$F=\log(x)-\frac 1y \log(y)=0\implies F'_x=\frac{1}{x}\qquad F'_y=\frac{\log (y)}{y^2}-\frac{1}{y^2}$$ Now, from the implicit function theorem $$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{F'_x}{F'_y}=\frac{y^2}{x-x \log (y)}$$ If now you replace $x$ by $y^y$, you effectively get $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y^{2-y}}{1-\log (y)}$$

Sooner or later, you will know that the solution of $x=y^{\frac{1}{y}}$ is explicitely given by $$y=-\frac{W(-\log (x))}{\log (x)}$$ where appears [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) and that $$\frac{dW(z)}{dz}=\frac{W(z)}{z (W(z)+1)}$$ Applying the chain rule, you would have $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{W(-\log (x))^2}{x \log ^2(x) (1+W(-\log (x)))}$$